# How to Bind Data in DropDown and Grid In classic Asp?

Tags: asp-classic

Hello I m new with asp scripts i have not mores ideas as well in asp. i have worked in asp.net.
Now I facing a problem to bind data with DropDown and Grid.
Please suggest me any ideas to bind data with drop down.
And  second thing how can i want to bind data with Grid with sorting feature.

Please Suggest me Idea to do this.

Comment: What Grid and what DropDown? I don't believe there are any controls integrated with ASP classic.

Comment: I want show the values in this manner Please Suggest me how can i do this.

Answer (score 2):

Classic ASP has no support for binding.

You best bet is using some jQuery Table plugin that supports sorting (like [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) or [others](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-great-jquery-plugins-for-better-table-manipulation/)), but you will need to do the data population yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
for a drop down

datasource = execute.sql 

<select id="">
<% for loop iterating through datasource%>
<option value="<%=datasource("value")%>"><%=datasource("text")%></option>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are technically incorrect.  Classic asp did have support for binding.  But it wasn't good.  It was the InterDev drag and drop controls.  See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260778(v=vs.60).aspx
"Introduction

The Grid Design-Time Control (DTC) is a Microsoft® ActiveX® control that creates HTML tables. The Grid DTC is a data-bound control that uses the Recordset DTC to retrieve data from a data source and displays the information in an HTML table."

But it is multiple versions of obsoleted, and is 1998 technology.  So even though it exists, pretend that it doesn't and don't try to use it.